# Deep Learning Virtual Machine can't run jupyter "No such notebook dir: ''/dsvm/Notebooks''"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, jupyter-notebook

I've set up a vm with Deep Learning Virtual Machine (Microsoft Azure).

Normally, I connect to the vm thanks to ssh etc

Then I run jupyter by writing `jupyter notebook --no-browser`.

But this time I have can't run jupyter notebook because there is this message  `Bad config encountered during initialization: "No such notebook dir: ''/dsvm/Notebooks''"`

How can I fix that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are trying to run Jupyter Notebook and with that goal in mind, I suggest you follow the following steps:

1. Move your notebook to ~/notebooks/
2. Find your Pubic IP Address of your VM from Azure Dashboard
3. Access https://your_public_ip_address:8000 in your web browser and log in using your vm login credentials
4. You should be able to see all the files you have in ~/notebooks/

I presume this method is defined by Azure for security reasons, to prevent people from having an open port without authentication. Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. No idea why the server status is not updated on the shell though.

Comment: I can't access jupyter notebook through the browser. I've tried https://my-public-ip:8000 and I even opened a port 9999 but nothing works. I can remote into my VM using putty though - can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me :

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/home/$USER/notebooks --no-browser
```